# Can we open any third party URL in Microsoft Teams chat bot using Adaptive Cards

Tags: c#, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I've created one project having details of products for Microsoft Teams it consists chat bot using adaptive cards it is displaying data with navigation URL but unable to open that URL in teams but opening in browser

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show what you've tried so far and link to any documentation you're following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution it can be done this way

string encodedContext = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("{\"subEntityId\":}");

URL:
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/{app_id}/{entity_id}?label=&context=encodedContext

same has been shared using JS as well 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links